# Checking sha1 against stored sha1 password

Tags: php, mysql, passwords, sha1

I'm hashing a password using sha1 and it is successfully storing it in the database, however i cannot seem to properly check to see if the sha1 matches one that is in the database. I've tried numerous different iterations of the below code, but nothing seems to work - what am i missing?

Registration

```
<?php 

$username = $_POST['username'];

$password = $_POST['password'];
$passwordEncrypted = sha1($password);

try {   

    $result = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO 
                            user_info 
                            SET 
                            username = :user,
                            pass = :pass
                            ");
    $result->bindParam(':user', $username);
    $result->bindParam(':pass', $passwordEncrypted);
    $result->execute();
}

catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Could not create username";
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
    foreach ($_POST as $field) {
        if (empty($field)) {
            $fail = true;
        }
        else {
            $continue = false;
        }
    }
    if ($field == $fail) {
        echo "You must enter a username and/or password";
    }
    else {
        echo "Your account has been successfully created.";
    }
}

?>
```

Logging in

```
<?php 

$username = $_POST['username'];          
$password = $_POST['password'];

$encryptedPassword = sha1($password);

try {   

$result = $db->prepare("SELECT username, pass FROM user_info WHERE username = :user AND BINARY pass = :pass");
$result->bindParam(':user', $username);
$result->bindParam(':pass', $password);
$result->execute();
$rows = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
}

catch (Exception $e) {
echo "Could not retrieve data from database";
exit();
}

if ($rows) {
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
$_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
include("inc/redirect.php");

} else {
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    echo "Username or password incorrect (passwords are case sensitive)";
}
}

?>
```

Comment: you have to do the same thing on both sides - your validation doesn't call `sha1`.

Comment: Add `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened, if you're not already doing so.

Answer (score 3):

You need to hash the password before querying the table, not afterwards:

```
<?php 

$username = $_POST['username'];          
$password = $_POST['password'];
$passwordEncrypted = sha1($password);

try {   

    $result = $db->prepare("SELECT username, pass FROM user_info WHERE username = :user AND BINARY pass = :pass");
    $result->bindParam(':user', $username);
    $result->bindParam(':pass', $passwordEncrypted);
    $result->execute();

    if ($result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
        include("inc/redirect.php");

    } else {
        if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
            echo "Username or password incorrect (passwords are case sensitive)";
        }
    }
}

catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Could not retrieve data from database";
    exit();
}

?>
```

Comment: This throws an error, i have to store the `sha1($password)` in a variable, but even then, the code doesn't work.

Comment: `Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in /home/maver08/public_html/design/inc/users.database.php on line 11`

Comment: So i did `$encryptedPassword = sha1($password);` and passed `$encryptedPassword` to the `:pass` - but still not working unfortunately

Comment: What happens when you use the variable?

Comment: FWIW, you don't need a reference if you use `bindValue()`, or if you simply pass the values in an array to `execute()`.

Comment: @shmosel it throws an incorrect username/password error

Comment: I think the problem is the scope of `$rows`. Editing my answer.

Comment: Not sure where the problem is. I would recommend adding some logging of the relevant variables, i.e. `$username`, `$password`, `$encryptedPassword`, and seeing if they all contain the values you expect.

Comment: For what it's worth, when i try to login now i can login using a non-sha1 password, but when trying to login using a password that has be sha1'd, it fails. Updated my code above.

Comment: If you're able to log in with a non-hashed password, obviously you saved a plain-text password in the database.

Comment: Yeah, i did, for testing. But what i'm saying is there's something wrong with the sha1 somewhere i guess. When i login with the sha1 of a password (taken from the table directly) it returns `$rows` and shows me the username and password when doing `var_dump($rows)`... Very odd?

Comment: If the hash is saved in the database, and your code is not hashing the password before testing it, then it makes perfect sense that you would have to pass the actual hash as your login password. Conversely, if the plain-text password is saved in the database, the login would obviously fail if the code tried hashing it.

Comment: I tested this, and everything checks out. I commented out the `include("inc/redirect.php");` line and replaced it with and echo. (For the OP)=> Also, this conditional statement `if (isset($_POST['login'])){` doesn't make sense and it won't echo `echo "Username or password incorrect (passwords are case sensitive)";` it should only read as `else{ echo "Username or password incorrect (passwords are case sensitive)";}`

Comment: The issue was my password field was a VARCHAR(8) instead of VARCHAR(40), since sha1 stores 40 characters. How embarrassing.

Comment: @NikkiMather You're welcome. I always set my password fields to `255`. Doing `50` wouldn't hurt ;-)